# Does pyrebase allow sms verification

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication

`pyrebase` has `sign_in_with_email_and_password` method for email login. Is there any method for sms verification using pyrebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick scan of the [Pyrebase source code](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/blob/7a652e6bd9d148da5ff6dbe7548c6d5d0dfa1109/pyrebase/pyrebase.py#L72) it seems to only implement email+password authentication.

A feature request was filed to [add phone verification](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/202), but it was closed as not feasible.